# jquery find and replace &lt; with ">"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to use jquery to find `&lt;` or `&gt;` and replace it with `<` or `>`. The idea is to change this from a text element into a live div tag.

I have this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jkawLqdp/2/) but it doesn't seem to be replacing those characters correctly because I still see "" in the output.

```
$('#myText').each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text();
      text = text.replace("&lt;", "/\</g");
      text = text.replace("&gt;", "/\>/g");
      $(this).text(text).clone().appendTo("#output").css("color", "blue");
      preventDefault;
    });
```

Why isn't this turning into a live div?

Comment: What is a "live div"?

Comment: Did you mean to do `$(this).html($(this).text())`? But I really don't see any reason why the text would contain html entities

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try changing `.text()` to use `.html()`

```
$(this).html(text).clone().appendTo("#output").css("color", "blue");
```

Comment: This worked then I changed it so that I cloned the first div then ran the find and replace. I wanted to keep the first div the same to show the div as a text element. Thank you! https://jsfiddle.net/jkawLqdp/4/

Comment: No problem. Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using .text() function and .text() is equivalent to innerText in standard javascript, try to use .html(), which is equivalent to innerHTML, instead and most probably it will work.

Comment: Most probably? Why not edit his fiddle and let us know if it **does**?

Comment: I am not on my device ;) I am writing from my phone and preferred to answer him.